# To many merge conflicts during `git rebase`

Tags: git, git-rebase

Just curious,

In case I was working on a branch `A` and made one commit

Another person was working on branch `master` and added / changed a ton of code

After I did `rebase --continue` I had to go through all the changes another person did, make decent choice which changes should I keep and which to delete, and that's

Is't it too much work? Taking into account that the benefit is only removing duplicate commits.

Comment: `Taking into account that the benefit is only removing duplicate commits.` Why duplicate commits? You would need to fix the conflicts with a 3-way-merge, too.

Comment: If there are merge-conflicts, only then you will need to go through the changes to resolve the conflicts. Even if you were using merge instead of rebase command, you would have to go through the changes to resolve the conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Some elements to take in consideration are :

1. how many commits separate `A` and `master` since their fork point
   if there are 8 commits on `A`, that's 8 commits to reapply on top of `master`, and so many more occasions to trigger conflicts
2. how many files were changed on `A`
   again, if your changes / the changes on `A` impact 50 files, the chances for conflicts will be higher than if they impact only 5 files.

---

One note on `1.` : if for some reason branch `A` (or `master`) was edited with a command which edited history (say : `git rebase -i HEAD~5` to remove some obvious mistakes 5 commits ago, or `git filter-branch` to remove something from all history ...), then the so called "fork point" will move up higher in the history.

Inspect the history of your `A` branch versus the history of `master` : if the only thing you actually need to rebase is your single commit, `git cherry-pick mycommit` (run from `master`) would be enough.

---

Regarding conflicts solving : some tools help you to "merge quicker".

For example : `meld` has a `--auto-merge` option.
You can set it on as your default mergetool (adapted from [this blog post](https://marcin-chwedczuk.github.io/use-meld-as-git-merge-diff-tool)) :

```
# in your ~/.gitconfig, add the following entries :
[merge]
    tool = meldauto

[mergetool "meldauto"]
    cmd = meld --auto-merge \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$REMOTE\" --output \"$MERGED\" --label \"MERGE (REMOTE BASE MY)\"
    trustExitCode = false
```

I haven't read the documentatioin for all other mergetools (`kdiff3`, `winmerge`, ...), but you may find an equivalent option for these too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 1 commit on your branch - A then:
(In case more than 1, then squash your commits into 1 commit. Or you can cherry-pick 1 by 1)

1. copy your short commit id in your branch
2. create another branch as A1 -> cherry-pick your commit via `git cherry-pick commit_id`
3. Delete A and rename branch A1 to A, or you just use the new branch A1